# Unable to boot ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, package-management

---

I have my hp probook 445 g1 ubuntu installed factory state.
I was running out of boot space on my PC so I installed ubuntu-tweak to clean it.But it didn't worked. After that an error symbol is placed on top which says package has unmet dependencies. After that removed links from software update excluding the top four.

After when I restarted my PC it got stuck on purple screen.

What to do now?????? plz help me I have lot of saved in there

HOw to boot my pc now

Answer (score 0):

at this point it sounds like you have some corrupted system files. use the livecd to copy the files you need to save to a usb just in case, then reinstall using the same username and password, it should carry over the packages and home folder. Sorry it got to that point, sir.

Comment: plzz can you explain in detail about how to fix it...........I think you are right because I failed to remove old kernals from ubuntu tweak and thats where the problem started. Now in recovery mode when i run in sudo `sudo apt-get -f install` it shows ERROR were encountered while processing:
linux-image-3.5.0-45-generic
linux-image-3.5.0-46-generic
linux-image-3.5.0-47-generic
linux-image-3.5.0-48-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: I really don't know how to "remotely" (outside of normal boot in the same OS) install a kernel, you could try installing a new install then copy over the kernel contents from the boot partition, but to be honest I really think it would be better to just do a standard reinstall